# ExpandableListView.getAdapter() returning android.widget.ExpandableListConnector

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

In my project I am trying to access the adapter(`BaseExpandableListAdapter`)  set to a  ExpandableListView by calling `getAdapter()` method. But `getAdapter()` returns `android.widget.ExpandableListConnector`.

here is my code

```
mExpandableListView.setAdapter(new ItemsExpListAdapter(navigationDrawerItems, getActivity()));
Log.e("adapter" , mExpandableListView.getAdapter().getClass().toString());
```

And I am getting in logcat like this

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use:

```
mExpandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter();
```